# perform map inside a map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code:

```
_renderChannels() {
     return this.state.channelsData.map(channelData => {
       return this.state.channelsStreamData.map(channelStreamData => {
          return <Channel channelData={channelData} channelStreamData={channelStreamData} />
      })
    });
  }
```

I want to map props on Channel component but Channel component is being returned 9 times repeatedly when it's supposed to be only 3 times? So I want to map the data of channelData and channelStreamData and return the component Channel. I tried removing the map inside of it but it's not returned when I don't return it. Help?

Comment: Right after the first `.map`, replace `channelData` with `(channelData, i)`, then return `<Channel channelData={channelData} channelStreamData={this.state.channelStreamData[i]} />` (you are running a 3 loop inside a 3 loop, giving you 3x3 elements)

Comment: @ChrisG sorry i am confused. Can I ask you to please make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
_renderChannels() {
    return this.state.channelsData.map((channelData, i) => <Channel 
        channelData={channelData}
        channelStreamData={this.state.channelStreamData[i]}
    />);
}
```

I've added `i`, the index parameter. That way I can grab the same element from the `this.state.channelStreamData` array.

Comment: was making two ajax request and had to separate. have not thought that way. thank you